# Name 'NewPage' is not defined in object oriented programming

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
import sqlite3

# make database and users (if not exists already) table at programme start up
with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEX NOT NULL);')
db.commit()
db.close()

#main Class
class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # Window 
        self.master = master
        # Some Usefull variables
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.n_username = StringVar()
        self.n_password = StringVar()
        #Create Widgets
        self.widgets()

    def NewPage():
        global NewRoot
        root.withdraw() # hide (close) the root/Tk window
        NewRoot = tk.Toplevel(root)
        # use the NewRoot as the root now

    #Login Function
    def login(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        #Find user If there is any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?')
        c.execute(find_user,[(self.username.get()),(self.password.get())])
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result:
            self.logf.pack_forget()
            self.head['text'] = self.username.get() + '\n Logged In'
            self.head['pady'] = 150
            root.after(2000, NewPage)
        else:
            ms.showerror('Oops!','Username Not Found.')

    def new_user(self):
        #Establish Connection
        with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        #Find Existing username if any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?')
        c.execute(find_user,[(self.username.get())])        
        if c.fetchall():
            ms.showerror('Error!','Username Taken Try a Diffrent One.')
        else:
            ms.showinfo('Success!','Account Created!')
            self.log()
        #Create New Account 
        insert = 'INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES(?,?)'
        c.execute(insert,[(self.n_username.get()),(self.n_password.get())])
        db.commit()

        #Frame Packing Methords
    def log(self):
        self.username.set('')
        self.password.set('')
        self.crf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'LOGIN'
        self.logf.pack()
    def cr(self):
        self.n_username.set('')
        self.n_password.set('')
        self.logf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'Create Account'
        self.crf.pack()

    #Draw Widgets
    def widgets(self):
        self.head = Label(self.master,text = 'LOGIN',font = ('',35),pady = 10)
        self.head.pack()
        self.logf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10)
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Username: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.username,bd = 5,font = ('',15)).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self.logf,text = 'Password: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.logf,textvariable = self.password,bd = 5,font = ('',15),show = '*').grid(row=1,column=1)
        Button(self.logf,text = ' Login ',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.login).grid()
        Button(self.logf,text = ' Create Account ',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.cr).grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.logf.pack()

        self.crf = Frame(self.master,padx =10,pady = 10)
        Label(self.crf,text = 'Username: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.crf,textvariable = self.n_username,bd = 5,font = ('',15)).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self.crf,text = 'Password: ',font = ('',20),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky = W)
        Entry(self.crf,textvariable = self.n_password,bd = 5,font = ('',15),show = '*').grid(row=1,column=1)
        Button(self.crf,text = 'Create Account',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.new_user).grid()
        Button(self.crf,text = 'Go to Login',bd = 3 ,font = ('',15),padx=5,pady=5,command=self.log).grid(row=2,column=1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Create Object
    #and setup window
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Login Form')
    #root.geometry('400x350+300+300')
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

On line 37 it says NewPage is not defined but I defined it on line 24, please help. this program is object oriented and im a student trying to complete this for my A-Level project. I dont understand alot of this code but any help would be much appreciated. Im a amateur when it comes to python/tkinter/sqlite but need this help otherwise I will fail my course because my teacher is not much help when it comes to programming

Comment: Which is line 37? Which is 24? What is the _full_ error? It doesn't look like the code in the question is properly indented either.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: On my screen it is all correctly indented, line 37 is root.after(2000, NewPage) and 24 is def NewPage():

Comment: i fixed my indentations

Comment: @NeilCousins `NewPage` is a method, just define and use it like you do with the other methods in the class. Why are you doing it different?

Comment: @Goyo I took it from another code and thought it would work. I’m not sure how I would go about doing it the way you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `self` in your function `def NewPage(self):`  and go to the line which you have `root.after(2000, NewPage)` and replace it with `root.after(2000, self.NewPage)`

Comment: make sure you select the correct answer by ticking the mark sign beside the answer for future reference.